# SAS do loop + lag function?

Tags: sql, loops, sas, lag

This is my first post, so please let me know if I'm not clear enough. Here's what I'm trying to do - this is my dataset. My approach for this is a do loop with a lag but the result is rubbish.

```
data a;
input @1 obs @4 mindate mmddyy10. @15 maxdate mmddyy10.;
format mindate maxdate date9.;
datalines;
1   01/02/2013 01/05/2013
2   01/02/2013 01/05/2013
3   01/02/2013 01/05/2013
4   01/03/2013 01/06/2013
5   02/02/2013 02/08/2013
6   02/02/2013 02/08/2013
7   02/02/2013 02/08/2013
8   03/10/2013 03/11/2013
9   04/02/2013 04/22/2013
10  04/10/2013 04/22/2013
11  05/04/2013 05/07/2013
12  06/10/2013 06/20/2013
;
run;
```

Now, I'm trying to produce a new column - "Replacement" based on the following logic:

1. If a record's mindate occurs before its lag's maxdate, it cannot be a replacement for it. If it cannot be a replacement, skip forward (so- 2,3,4 cannot replace 1, but 5 can).
2. Otherwise... if the mindate is less than 30 days, Replacement = Y. If not, replacement = N. Once a record replaces another (so, in this case, 5 does replace 1, because 02/02/2013 is <30 than 01/05/2013, it cannot duplicate as a replacement for another record. But if it's an N for one record above, it can still be a Y for some other record. So, 6 is now evaluated against 2, 7 against 3,etc. Since those two combos are both "Y", 8 is now evaluated versus 4, but because its mindate >30 relative to 4's maxdate, it's a N. But, it's then evaluated against against
3. And so on...

I should that in a 100 record dataset, this would imply that the 100th record could technically replace the 1st, so I've been trying lags within loops. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated! Expected output:

```
                      obs      mindate      maxdate    Replacement

                        1    02JAN2013    05JAN2013
                        2    02JAN2013    05JAN2013
                        3    02JAN2013    05JAN2013
                        4    03JAN2013    06JAN2013
                        5    02FEB2013    08FEB2013         Y
                        6    02FEB2013    08FEB2013         Y
                        7    02FEB2013    08FEB2013         Y
                        8    10MAR2013    11MAR2013         Y
                        9    02APR2013    22APR2013         Y
                       10    10APR2013    22APR2013         N
                       11    04MAY2013    07MAY2013         Y
                       12    10JUN2013    20JUN2013         Y
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output? I'm thinking a SQL self join is what you'll need to do instead of loops/lags. Any code you've tried is helpful as well :)

Comment: @Reeza - this could probably also be done using a double DOW-loop.

Comment: @ Reeza. Thanks. The expected output is:

Comment: Are you sure that replacement = Y for obs = 12? The mindate of 10th June is more than 30 days after any of the previous maxdates.

Comment: @user667489 - Yes, you're right.

Comment: @user667489. One more thing I wanted to ask you - I've always ignored arrays due to not having to use them or finding some other way. I can see now that in such a situation they are very useful. Can you tell me in what situations you rely on them; when do you they come in especially handy? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is correct if the asker was mistaken about replacement = Y for obs = 12.

```
/*Get number of obs so we can build a temporary array to hold the dataset*/
data _null_;
    set have nobs= nobs;
    call symput("nobs",nobs);
    stop;
run;

data want;
    /*Load the dataset into a temporary array*/
    array dates[2,&NOBS] _temporary_;
    if _n_ = 1 then do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(eof);
        set have end = eof;
        dates[1,_n_] = maxdate;
        dates[2,_n_] = 0;
    end;

    set have;

    length replacement $1;

    replacement = 'N';
    do i = 1 to _n_ - 1 until(replacement = 'Y');
        if dates[2,i] = 0 and 0 <= mindate - dates[1,i] <= 30 then do;
            replacement = 'Y';
            dates[2,i] = _n_;
            replaces = i;
        end;
    end;
    drop i; 
run;
```

You could use a hash object + hash iterator instead of a temporary array if you preferred. I've also included an extra var, `replaces`, to show which previous row each row replaces.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. And yes, I was mistaken regarding Obs = 12, as it does turn out to be more than 30 days.

Comment: Nice, I've never considered `do * by * until` or overloading `_N_`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using SQL and hash tables. It is not optimal but it was the first method that sprang to mind.

```
/* Join the input with its self */
proc sql;
    create table b as
    select 
        a1.obs, 
        a2.obs as obs2
    from a as a1
    inner join a as a2
        /* Set the replacement criteria */
        on a1.maxdate < a2.mindate <= a1.maxdate + 30
    order by a2.obs, a1.obs;
quit;
/* Create a mapping for replacements */
data c;
    set b;
    /* Create two empty hash tables so we can look up the used observations */
    if _N_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h();
        h.definekey("obs");
        h.definedone(); 
        declare hash h2();
        h2.definekey("obs2");
        h2.definedone();
    end;
    /* Check if we've already used this observation as a replacement */
    if h2.find() then do;
        /* Check if we've already replaced his observation  */
        if h.find() then do;
            /* Add the observations to the hash table and output */
            h2.add();
            h.add();
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
/* Combine the replacement map with the original data */
proc sql;
    select 
        a.*, 
        ifc(c.obs, "Y", "N") as Replace, 
        c.obs as Replaces
    from a
    left join c
        on a.obs = c.obs2
    order by a.obs;
quit;
```

There are several ways in which this can be simplified:

- The dates can be brought through the first `proc sql`
- The `if` statements can be combined
- The final join could be replaced by a little extra logic in the data step

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't think of using hash tables but I can see how it comes in handy here.