# select unique combination in two overlap datasets

Tags: sql, join, sas, combinations, datastep

For example, in SAS, I have 5 IDs in dataset A(below left). There is a dataset B,(could potentially contain some A's IDs,below right).What I need is to find one unique combination( A is the primary outcome dataset)  on A and B has same sex, age range within 5 and income range within 10000.Tt is possible that there are a lot of b.id could merge with a.id. But here's the kick, I can only use b.id once. In this case, 101 merge with  106, 102 merge with 111,103 merge with 112,105 merge with 110. Sorry I have a hard time how to describe my question. Hopefully it is clear enough. Thanks!

```
ID  sex  age   income                 ID    sex    age   income
101  F    30    20000                 106    F      26    21000
102  M    20    10000                 102    M      20    10000
103  F    38    30000                 110    M      45    44000
104  M    55    35000                 111    M      19    14000
105  M    43    45000                 112    F      33    34000
```

outcome

```
    ID_a  sex_a  age_a   income_a    ID_b    sex_b    age_b   income_b
      101  F    30    20000                 106    F      26    21000
      102  M    20    10000                 111    M      19    14000
      103  F    38    30000                 112    F      33    34000
      104  M    55    35000                 
      105  M    43    45000                 110    M      45    44000
```

Comment: Can you show us what query you have attempted, so we can help point out the issue with your approach?

Comment: No, I don't understand. What links 101 to 106? By what rule do you pair the records?

Comment: in real case, I have 100 unique IDs in A, 300 unique IDs in B, it is possible that there are a lot of b.id could merge with a.id. But here's the kick, I can only use b.id once. I thought this is not a single left join I can do...maybe in SQL we have some function could solve this puzzle?

Comment: Hi Thorsten Kettner. I add an outcome ....

Comment: Well, I still don't get it. I still don't know why you combine 101 with 106 and not with 112 for instance. What is the rule for combining two records? (BTW: use @Thorsten Kettner in order to reply. Otherwise I get no notification and probably don't come back.)

Comment: It seems you are pairing at most one B row with each A row, and you say you must not pair any one B row with more than one A row.  Unfortunately, there is not, in general, a unique way to do that.  If you care about which of possibly many solutions is chosen, then you'll have to explain which you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.Id, b.Id from SetA a
left join SetB b on a.sex = b.sex and 
a.age between b.age - 5 and b.age + 5 and 
a.income between b.income - 10000 and b.income + 10000
```

Comment: Hi Ricky. Thanks for the code. How should I deal with multiple b.id merge with a.id? and the same b.id possibly merge with different a.id? I do want an unique combination..

Comment: You mean they might contain the same ids.
Then I suggest you add: 
    and a.id <> b.id
at the end

Comment: hmmmm. that's one of the things. Maybe I should explain this way: B is  like a pool. Every time there's an a.id match in B, I pull that id out from B and can not put it back. Thanks a lot. I just have a hard time to sort it out :(

Comment: You mean that the pool a.Id can have many matches to b.Id.
But b.Id may only have one match to a.Id?
In that case, what defines the best match for b.Id?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the techniques used in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423622/sas-do-loop-lag-function) to do your fuzzy matching while making sure that each b.id is only used once.

The idea is to load your B dataset into a temporary array / hash object, so you can keep track of which b.ids have already been used while matching it onto A.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    B.ID
FROM lefttable A
INNER JOIN righttable B
ON (A.sex = B.sex) AND (A.age BETWEEN B.age -5 AND B.age + 5) AND (A.income BETWEEN B.income -10000 AND B.age + 10000)
```